# Spring Boot app with Eureka DiscoveryClient fails to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, discovery, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to write a simple Spring Boot application that can (1) register with a Netflix Eureka server, and (2) query the Eureka server to retrieve details of other registered services.

My client class has an `@Autowired` field of type `com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient` that is used to talk to Eureka and query it to learn about other services. On my main class I have the annotation `@EnableDiscoveryClient`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AppBootstrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppBootstrap.class, args);
    }

}
```

In my `application.yml` file under src/main/resources I have:

```
eureka:
    instance:
         lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 10
         lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 20
         prefer-ip-address: true
         secure-port: 443
         non-secure-port: 80
         metadata-map:
             instanceId: my-test-instance
    client:
         service-url:
             defaultZone: http://localhost:9080/eureka/
         registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 6
         instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 6
         register-with-eureka: true
         fetch-registry: true
         heartbeat-executor-thread-pool-size: 5
         eureka-service-url-poll-interval-seconds: 10
```

When I start my app the service fails to boot, throwing an exception that is rooted at:

**Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaInstanceConfigBean.getInstanceI
d()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.netflix.appinfo.providers.EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider.get(EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider
.java:53)
        at com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager.initComponent(ApplicationInfoManager.java:90)
        ... 25 more**

I've no idea what's going on here. Any ideas? I believe the app should still start even if my Eureka config is incorrect, but it falls over at start time.

Secondly, am I using the correct DiscoveryClient? Ideally I'd like to make it general such that I could use it with Eureka, Consul or ZooKeeper as examples. I find the documentation isn't great at illucidating exactly what's required when using these Spring Cloud / Netflix discovery components.

Comment: You are using a version of `eureka-client` that is incompatible with Spring Cloud Netflix. To avoid problems like this you should make use of Spring Cloud's dependency management.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Spring Cloud dependency management. ..can you give me an example?

Comment: It depends on whether you're using Maven or Gradle. Try searching for `bom` in [the documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient
```

then you can get the list of instances with discoveryClient.getInstances

```
ServiceInstance instance = discoveryClient.getInstances(service).get(0);
instance.getUri().toString();
```

If you use another components like RestTemplate, Ribbon, etc you only need to use the name of the service (name registered in eureka) in the URL

```
restTemplate.getForObject("http://PRODUCTSMICROSERVICE/products/{id}", Product.class, id)
```

You can see more here

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Answer (score 0):

I received the autowiring error in my experience when i was using discoveryclient to get the information in the class outside any function. So I was using eureka to find out the port for my service as the port was described as 0 hence service was picking up port dynamically while starting as spring boot application. I needed to know the port programmatically . In the controller i used the code like below in wrong way

```
public class HelloController {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);

@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

int port = discoveryClient.getLocalServiceInstance().getPort();


@RequestMapping("/hello/{id}")
public String  sayhello(@PathVariable String id)
{
    String s ="A very nice and warm welcome to the world "+id;
            LOG.info(String.format("calling helloservice for %s",id));
    LOG.info(String.format("calling helloservice for port %d",port));
    return s;
}
```

Once i put the port code inside the sayhello method the error went away. So the correct way of retreiving the port is as below

```
public class HelloController {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);

@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;



@RequestMapping("/hello/{id}")
public String  sayhello(@PathVariable String id)
{
    String s ="A very nice and warm welcome to the world "+id;
    int port = discoveryClient.getLocalServiceInstance().getPort();
    LOG.info(String.format("calling helloservice for %s",id));
    LOG.info(String.format("calling helloservice for port %d",port));
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are using the latest versions of Spring Boot then we wouldn't require the @EnableDiscoveryClient or @EnableEurekaClient to be defined in the main class. This happens in the background by Spring when we add the dependencies in pom.xml

Please make sure your files have the below basic informations.

**pom.xml**

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**application.properties** or YAML file as per choice

```
spring.application.name=eureka-client

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address= true
server.port= 8082
```

No changes or @ Annotations required in the main class in Application.java

Please checkout my [GIT Repository here](https://github.com/yellowstone-bbc/Spring-Boot-Concepts-/tree/EurekaClient) for the working code.

Answer (score 0):

add application.yml file these settings;

## Our product application run at this port

server :
port : 8482

## Our service will be register by own service name

spring :
application :
name : product-service

```
# To be register we assign eureka service url
eureka:
   client:
     service-url :
        defaultZone:
            ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8481/eureka} # add your port where your eureka server running
   instance :
      prefer-ip-address : true

# Logging file path
logging :
   file :
      path : target/${spring.application.name}.log
```